# Run `bash` command on Jenkins in windows hang forever

Tags: jenkins

I am running Jenkins job on a windows10 machine. And I have installed `ubuntu shell` on the windows. The Jenkins job works fine with windows batch commands. But it stuck there when I try to run `bash` command. For example, I created an `Execute Windows batch command` build step, if I put command `bash -c ls`, this command never finishes.

It works fine if I run the same command in the windows directly.

How can I configure Jenkins job to work with `bash` command?

Below is the build step configuration. There are two commands. The first one is used to install dependencies on my nodejs application. The second command is used to run a command in `bash shell`. The problem is that the build is stuck on the second command.

[image]

Comment: This still seems to fail under the Fall Creator's Update.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made any Global configurations in jenkins. try giving the command with the home path of Ubuntu shell and re run the command once.

Comment: It may impact other build steps since it is a global configuration. Another thing is that I need to run the command in `Execute Windows batch command` step, because I have other btch commands need to run there.

Comment: Did Scripts file executed successfully outside Jenkins ?

Comment: Have you tried to configure Ubuntu Shell in Jenkins(Like Git,Maven and Ant Configured in Jenkins). Can you able to show any screen how you have configured them in Jenkins(If possible).

Comment: I have posted a screen shot about how I configure the build step.

Comment: 1)What have installed in windows for executing bash.?
2)You need to configure that Path to your Jenkins environment.
3)You can the script by providing the path then the command
"sh path*.sh"

Comment: I have installed `ubuntu bash` on the windows. I am able to run `bash` command directly on windows. The problem is happening when I run `bash` command from `windows batch command` build step.

Comment: I you have installed Ubuntu Bash, why are you executing through Windows batch command you can try with shell in the option directly

Comment: that's because I need to use windows batch to trigger my test cases. Inside my test cases, I need to use `mtools` command to create my `mongodb` instance. `mtools` doesn't work on windows so I have to use `ubuntu bash` command. I found that my build step stuck on running `bash` command. So I tried to reproduce this issue by typing `bash -c ls` on the batch step.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Something about running under a service and bash seems to cause this. Any resolution or ideas?

Comment: I have also run jenkins by hand from the command line and then I bash works fine. Further, just tested on the Fall creator's update. It still fails. It might be time for a bug report.